# Programming Sound Recorder with c# for windows phone 8.0

Tags: c#

I have the following code with the following error message

> Error    1   'System.IO.MemoryStream' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetWavAsByteArray' and no extension method 'GetWavAsByteArray'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\Dansyo\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\DrumKit\DrumKit\playDrums.xaml.cs   121 34  DrumKit

This is the code

```
private void SaveTempAudio(MemoryStream buffer)
{
     using(IsolatedStorageFile isoStore=IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
     {
          var bytes = buffer.GetWavAsByteArray(_recorder.SampleRate);
          var tempFileName = "tempwav.wav";
          IsolatedStorageFileStream audioStream = isoStore.CreateFile(tempFileName);
          audioStream.Write(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
          AudioPlayer.SetSource(audioStream);
     }
}
```

Please help me solve these error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the tutorial at https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-20-Recording-an-Audio-Wav-File it seems you're missing a few references and/or dll's. Make sure to reference:

[image]

The import import is the `Coding4Fun.Toolkit.Audio.Helpers` namespace.